# Error running .py from Windows 7 command prompt

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am new to python and I have just installed python 2.7.3 on Windows. I will also install django so I need to execute a file named  ez_setup.py. I know it seems like an easy question and answer can be found in internet, but this is not the case. I tried lots of things and tried what internet says, the problem is still there and I cant find the problem!

I follow all the steps that is explained in tutorials in order for Python to work properly. (Installing steps and editing environment variables..)

Python's location is:

```
C:\Users\name\27
```

Command prompt starts like:

```
C:\Users\name>
```

I have put ez_setup.py file under both C:\Users\name\27  and C:\Users\name.

When I type "ez_setup.py" or "python ez_setup.py" or "\27 python ez_setup.py" and lot of combination, it says:

```
python: cant open file 'ez_setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

What should I do? Where do I make mistake?

Comment: The error shows that you are in the wrong directory. You should change the directory (cd command) of the command prompt to the directory where ez_setup.py is located or specify it with >> python <location of ez_setup.py>.

Comment: Downvote without leaving a comment? Thanks!

Comment: @AnkurAnkan I am in the same directory because I put the file to the all related directories

Comment: @Caren The error means that it can't find the file, that does mean that you are not in the directory where the file is located. You should probably double check if you are running the command from the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
python ez_setup.py
```

You need to say your machine that it should execute this .py file with python.

Comment: @Ceren Ok sry, but this was not clear from your question. Hopefully it works with the other answers.